# Mithril doesnt auto redraw the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, mithril.js

When changing prop values mithril doesnt auto redraw the view, on press of a button i update my prop as:

```
     something.vm.test(something.vm.test() + 1);
```

it updates the prop value but doesn't reflect on view by using m.redraw() it works fine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing props does not trigger redraw, but button click events should (and you should see the changes to the props).

Is it a mithril button using `onclick` attribute? Or non-mithril click event?
If you're not using a mithril event you'll need `m.redraw()`

Answer (score 1):

Basically, m.prop is a reactive data source. [this code](http://jsbin.com/qakuse/edit?html,js,output) may help you.

if you want to work outside of mithril block,
embrace prop with `m.startComputation()` and `m.endComputation()`

like this.

```
m.startComputation();
something.vm.test(something.vm.test() + 1);
m.endComputation();
```

it works like charm!

Comment: Yep I'm using that when I'm making third party service calls and I need to update a list of records. Like @spectrum said it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Note that modifying the values of m.prop getter-setters does not trigger redrawing, These functions are internally called by Mithril when you initialize a component via m.mount or m.route, and when you trigger event handlers that were created within templates with m().
So you can use the **m.prop()** if you want to change the value of **var**.
Look this example :

```
controller: function() {
    var list = [];
    var element = m.prop('');

function addElement() {
  list.push(element());
  element('');
}
return {
  list: list,
  value: element,
  addElement: addElement
}


    m('button',{
      onclick: ctrl.addElement
    }, 'Add')],
```

In this case element is a m.prop() and the value change when you click the button